# Use Dictionary (key) as input from user , then from same Dictionary load .csv files(value)

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering, load-csv

Here is how it looks like:

```
dictionary = { '1' : 'mine.csv' , '2' : 'yours.csv' , '3' : 'ours.csv' ...}
```

I want to ask user input :

```
def get_filters():

question = input('which file would you like to view its contents ?' , 1)
```

so answer should be like :
'1' >> it opens first file from dictionary to start filter.

I want all files to open from a single code :

```
def load_data(question, ..):
    df= pd.read_csv(dictionary[question])
```

since df is going to be used in filtering all data inside files.

but this does not load file , and program consider filtering output as tuples.

How to connect dictionary key and value to load data ,
like:
if input is key : load value .
Or simple other ways to do it?

Comment: 'but this does not load file , and program consider filtering output as tuples.' --- can you show more details of current behaviou?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the question, but you could use something like this:

```
def load_data():
    while True:
        question = input('which file would you like to view its contents ?')
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(dictionary[question])
            return df
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

This will take a user input, attempt to open a file. If it succeeds, it will return the df. If it fails, it will print the error and then let the user try again.

Comment: hi David , this worked great , it loaded the data  .